# How to get a single header column cell value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems so easy but I cannot figure out what I'm missing

```
Column_Name = excel_data_df.columns(0)

print (Column_Name)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 169, in 
> Column_Name = excel_data_df.columns(0) TypeError: 'Index' object is
> not callable

Do I need to index my headers and then call the specific index I'm looking for? I am just trying to print the header value of a specific row, but I only want the header value not the entire column

Comment: I should add here is the error I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 169, in <module>
    Column_Name = excel_data_df.columns(0)
TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable

Comment: And now I know how important the difference between () and [] is!. Worked by removing the (0) and replacing with [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering this so nobody wastes their time, fix was this below, simple misuse of ( rather than using the correct [.

```
Column_Name = excel_data_df.columns[0]

print (Column_Name)
```